# joda.time.DateTime with hibernate createQuery to setDate

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

pojo

```
public class RateCode implements java.io.Serializable {

     private org.joda.time.DateTime travelTo;
     private org.joda.time.DateTime bookingFrom;
}
```

Query

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
                "from RateCode rr where rr.id.date>=:from and rr.id.date<=:to order by rr.id.date").setDate("from", from).setDate("to", to);
```

But setDate/setTimeStamp Require util.Date.

```
ERROR: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TIMESTAMP
        at org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(PersistentDateTime.java:83)
```

so how to set in createQuery criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom user types created for joda-time. You can download it [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html)

[Persisting Joda DateTime instead of Java Date in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189167/persisting-joda-datetime-instead-of-java-date-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at my project, http://usertype.sourceforge.net/ which will let you map Joda Time to Hibernate.

Thanks Chris